# What is IPC:BufferIO in managed postgresql metrics on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql

I have a managed postgresql instance on AWS.

Sometimes the database session load seems excessive

[image]

in `RDS > Databases > [instance]` page

Then in the metrics I see the following graph:

[image]

My question is what is `IPC:BufferIO` I couldn't find anything in docs or google about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPC:BufferIO wait event is actually LWLock:BufferIO , starting from  PostgreSQL 14 BufferIO wait event moved from  LWLock wait event type to IPC wait event type , please check this [commit](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/32/3008/) and this [email thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CA+hUKGJ8nBFrjLuCTuqKN0pd2PQOwj9b_jnsiGFFMDvUxahj_A@mail.gmail.com) .

also above information already got mentioned in [AWS RDS for PostgreSQL Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/wait-event.lwlockbufferio.html)

"For RDS for PostgreSQL versions earlier than PostgreSQL 14, this wait event type is lwlock. For PostgreSQL 14 and later releases, the wait event type is IPC. "